# Export Webform submission data into external database

Tags: 7, webforms

I need webform submission data to be inserted into an external sql database.  How would I go about doing this? Would this be a custom module, or be processed in template.php?  I am having trouble understanding how I can capture that data and have it sent over to an external database.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the first step to solving a problem like this in Drupal is finding the right hook.

A quick google search for "webform hooks", and then we pick the hook where we'd have access to the completed webform's data: http://api.lullabot.com/hook_webform_submission_insert/7

The example on that page happens to be exactly what you want to do!

Comment: When adding a field to be inserted, as in the example from that link you provided, how do I write my own fields? 'foo' => 'foo_data',  How would I add a field called first_name? 'first_name' => 'first_name', doesn't work.